# Why is each number passed into the linked list not on a node?

Tags: javascript

All numbers are not being attached to a node.
I can not figure out why!
When I make nums an array, or parens, etc.
There are no nodes except for the last value or the entire array and I cannot figure out why.

I cannot rest... and spread..., if it's passed an array it just assigns the array to the 1st node, if it's in parens it just assigns the very last number to a node but skips everything else. And numbers that are just passed in are only added up to 2 deep.

```
function LinkedList(...values) {
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  for (const value of values) {
    this.push(value); 
  }
}
function Node(val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.next = null;
}
LinkedList.prototype.push = function (value) {
  const newNode = new Node(value);
  if (this.head === null) {
    this.head = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  } else {
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  }
};

LinkedList.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  let currentNode = this.head;
  while(currentNode) {
    if(currentNode.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }
  return false;
}

LinkedList.prototype.addToHead = function(value) {
  const newNode = new Node(value);
  newNode.next = this.head;
  this.head = newNode;
}
const nums = (4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22);
const LinkedList1 = new LinkedList(nums);
LinkedList1.push(1);
console.log(LinkedList1)

LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(value, position) {
  if(position === 0) {
    this.addToHead(value);
  }
  else {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let previousNode = null;
    let currentIndex = 0;
    while(currentIndex < position) {
      if(!currentNode) throw new Error('Position out of range');
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      currentIndex++;
    }
    previousNode.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = currentNode;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.removeItem = function(value) {
  if (!this.head) return; // If list is empty, do nothing
  if (this.head.value === value) {
    this.head = this.head.next;
    return;
  }
  let currentNode = this.head;
  while (currentNode.next && currentNode.next.value !== value) {
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }
  if (!currentNode.next) return;
  currentNode.next = currentNode.next.next;
  if(this.tail.value === value) {
    this.tail = currentNode;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.removePosition = function(position) {
  if(position === 0 && this.head) {
    this.head = this.head.next;
    return;
  }
  let currentNode = this.head;
  let previousNode = null;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  while(currentIndex < position) {
    if(!currentNode) throw new Error('Position out of range');
    previousNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
    currentIndex++;
  }
  if (!currentNode) return;
  previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
  if(this.tail === currentNode) {
    this.tail = previousNode;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are only passing a single value 22 to the constructor function because the expression `(4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22)` evaluates to value 22. See: [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator). Instead, directly pass the values: `new LinkedList(4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22)`

Answer (score 1):

`const nums = (4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22);` gives `22`, change to
`const nums = [4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22];`. That would be an array of the numbers.

The parentheses groups the expression which gives 22 because of the grouping, since without square brackets the commas become a comma operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator

```js
function LinkedList(...values) {
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  for (const value of values) {
    this.push(value); 
  }
}
function Node(val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.next = null;
}
LinkedList.prototype.push = function (value) {
  const newNode = new Node(value);
  if (this.head === null) {
    this.head = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  } else {
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  }
};

LinkedList.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  let currentNode = this.head;
  while(currentNode) {
    if(currentNode.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }
  return false;
}

LinkedList.prototype.addToHead = function(value) {
  const newNode = new Node(value);
  newNode.next = this.head;
  this.head = newNode;
}
const nums = [4, 5, 8, 2, 0, 4, 22];
const LinkedList1 = new LinkedList(nums);
LinkedList1.push(1);
console.log(LinkedList1)

LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(value, position) {
  if(position === 0) {
    this.addToHead(value);
  }
  else {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let previousNode = null;
    let currentIndex = 0;
    while(currentIndex < position) {
      if(!currentNode) throw new Error('Position out of range');
      previousNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      currentIndex++;
    }
    previousNode.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = currentNode;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.removeItem = function(value) {
  if (!this.head) return; // If list is empty, do nothing
  if (this.head.value === value) {
    this.head = this.head.next;
    return;
  }
  let currentNode = this.head;
  while (currentNode.next && currentNode.next.value !== value) {
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }
  if (!currentNode.next) return;
  currentNode.next = currentNode.next.next;
  if(this.tail.value === value) {
    this.tail = currentNode;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.removePosition = function(position) {
  if(position === 0 && this.head) {
    this.head = this.head.next;
    return;
  }
  let currentNode = this.head;
  let previousNode = null;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  while(currentIndex < position) {
    if(!currentNode) throw new Error('Position out of range');
    previousNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
    currentIndex++;
  }
  if (!currentNode) return;
  previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
  if(this.tail === currentNode) {
    this.tail = previousNode;
  }
}
```